# Set custom selection color in FSCalender for selected dates

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

Hi I am new to iOS and was working to create a calendar using FSCalendar which is pretty awesome but I am unable to change the selection color of the range of dates in between the first selected date and last selected date. They are all of same colors. I want to display a lighter tone in between the two dates. For Example: Apart from 2nd Dec and 5th Dec in the screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWXh.jpg), all the dates should be a different color.

How do I change the color of the dates inside the range excluding the final and initial dates?

Answer (score 2):

By using `FSCalendarDelegateAppearance` you can control the selection fill color for individual dates.

**Step 1. Ensure you have set the delegate:**

```
yourFSCalendarObject.delegate = self
```

**Step 2. Implement available `FSCalendarDelegateAppearance` delegate methods:**

In your case: `calendar(_:appearance:fillSelectionColorFor:)`

**Example:**

```
extension YourClassName: FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillSelectionColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
        //where startDate and endDate make the range of dates
        if date >= startDate, date <= endDate {
            return .yellow
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```